# CMOS imager digital number versus reflectance

Tags: image-processing

[image: Image of four reflectance targets]

The image linked above is captured by a camera shooting in RAW mode using an RGB CMOS imager. The image contains four calibrated reflectance targets, of 5.2%, 9.4%, 23.1% and 52%, reflectance, respectively. What I believed I would see in the image is digital numbers in each color channel from that part of the image corresponding to each target that are proportional to reflectance, e.g. DN / reflectance basically a constant within the same color channel of the image. This is based on literature that says DN = kI + b, where I is incident energy, k is a scaling constant, and b is the noise equivalent exposure DN. In other words, twice as much reflectance is twice as many photons.

That is not what I see. For example, the average red channel DN values for each target are 152, 217, 504, and 844, respectively (all values on a 10 bit scale).

This is what I know:

1. Gamma correction is turned off, so response should be linear.
2. According to the imager documentation, my measured noise equivalent exposure of 53 is typical, and those values have been subtracted from all of the DNs above.
3. All values taken from the same image and the same color channel from within that image.
4. All four targets are operating in the "linear" range of the focal plane array, not yet saturated and beyond the noise-dominated floor.

I subsequently took a picture in RAW mode with a DSLR camera and obtained similar results, with DN values of 51, 84, 175, 242. I don't have knowledge about whether noise equivalent exposure has been subtracted here or not, but the results are close enough to the other imager that I've concluded that I'm not understanding something fundamental here.

My question is: why is the measured DN not proportional to the percentage reflectance in the calibrated reflectance targets?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should get an idea of the accuracy of the measurements (in particular the standard deviation inside a small area, and across time). This will tell you if the non-linearity is significant or not. Also check uniformity of the lighting by imaging a white screen.

Comment: How did you get from RAW mode to RGB exactly?

Comment: @Mark These numbers are taken from the raw MIPI interface on this Sony IMX377 imager.  I only included the red channel values here.  According to the data sheet, the imager's DN should be linear with incident uJ/cm2. The MIPI interface is prior to injection of the FPA data into the processor's ISP, and the IMX377 does not do analog gamma correction in the chip.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The measurement was repeated altering the position of the squares in the FOV, taking multiple images under constant illuminant, and windowing each target to gather better variance estimates.  The measurements are consistent (standard deviation less than 4 DN in the red channel).  Your uniform target suggestion is very helpful, though.  In the raw image, we should see lens vignetting, and I will verify that we do.  If vignetting is not present, it may indicate that the FPA is doing manipulation  prior to the MIPI readout - not consistent with the documentation but not impossible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust vignetting is present in the raw photos, as hoped, so it seems likely that this truly is the raw DN in the photos.